# Polars - Declare pl.List - TypeError: 'DataTypeClass' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-polars

I'm trying to declare a dataframe with a column as a pl.list, like that :

```
cart_schema = [("CART_ID", pl.Int64), ("ORDERS", pl.List[pl.Int64]), ("TOTAL_DISTANCE", pl.Float64), ("TOTAL_WEIGHT", pl.Float64)]
carts = pl.DataFrame([], schema=cart_schema)
```

It obtains error : TypeError: 'DataTypeClass' object is not subscriptable

Only way, I found to do it is :

```
carts = pl.DataFrame({'CART_ID':0,'ORDERS':[ [0,1]],'TOTAL_DISTANCE':0.0,'TOTAL_WEIGHT':0 })
carts = carts.filter(pl.col("CART_ID") != 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error states: `Polars - Declare pl.List - TypeError: 'DataTypeClass' object is not subscriptable`

You are subscripting - the `[]` syntax - a `pl.List`, which is not allowed.

Instead you must initialize a `pl.List` data type by calling it - using the `()` syntax -.:

```py
pl.List(pl.Int64)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `[]`, Instead you can try using `{}`

```
cart_schema= [
("CART_ID", pl.Int64),
("ORDERS", pl.List(pl.Int64)),
("TOTAL_DISTANCE", pl.Float64),
("TOTAL_WEIGHT", pl.Float64)
]

carts = pl.DataFrame({}, schema=cart_schema)
print(carts)
```